# vim 9 ignoring stuff on `/usr/share/vim/vim90/`

Tags: vim, fedora

After an upgrade from Fedora 38 to 39, `vim` ignores its main runtime directory at `/usr/share/vim/vim90/`.

Even the simplest `:help` command fails with `E149: Sorry, no help for help.txt`, as its contents is on `/usr/share/vim/vim90/doc/help.txt`.

I have tried ignoring my `~/.vimrc` with `-u NONE -U NONE -N`, `--clean` and `-N -u /dev/null` and also tried `--noplugin`, to no avail.

I have also tried playing with `VIMRUNTIME`, setting it to only `/usr/share/vim/vim90`, and with the option `'runtimepath'`, nothing helped.

I can tell the problem is that `vim` is ignoring that directory, because if I try to use a plugin from there, such as `NoMatchParen`, I get an error (in this specific case, `E492: Not an editor command: NoMatchParen`), while the plugins (and docs) on `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles` work just fine.

The error seems not to be Fedora 39-related, but something on my computer, as I have other Fedora 39 machines (these upgraded from 37) where `vim` is working just fine.

I'm at a loss.  How do I debug this kind of problems on `vim`?

*Edit 1*

`vim -V` shows some references to the offending directory and no errors, yet whatever is sourced there is not available on the actual running command:

```
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin)
```

Forcing `vim` to read the plugin with `:runtime plugin/matchparen.vim` returns no errors, but is also not effective (ie `:NoMatchParen` is still not found)

*Edit 2*

Well, some stuff in `vim90` is actually read.  In special, the colorschemes there are available to use with `:colorscheme`.

Also, the sequence below works fine, so I'm no longer so sure about `vim90` being ignored.  Yet, why does `NoMatchParen` not work at `vim` start, if it is read (as per `vim -V`)?

```
:unlet g:loaded_matchparen
:runtime plugin/matchparen.vim
:NoMatchParen
```

*Edit 3*

The file `/usr/share/vim/vim90/doc/tags` is supposed to be provided by the package `vim-common.x86_64`, but it does not exist on the failing system.  Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145819/vim74-e149-sorry-no-help-for-help-txt, I could generate that myself, but if ran as root, which I don't want to.

*Edit 4*

This seems to be a bug...  Downgrading to `vim-common-2:9.0.1927-1.fc39.x86_64` made it work again.  I'll try to open a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

And...  That's a bug:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2250722

I'll keep the question/answer on the site for now, in case someone else experiences this issue (I had not found anything searching Google, and only found the bug when I was preparing to file a new one).

Comment: Wow!  The fix is in `updates-testing` already.